# Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined (Nuget)

Tags: nuget, momentjs

```
        var date1 = $('#StartDate').val();
        var date2 = $('#EndDate').val();

        var a = moment([date1]);
        var b = moment([date2]);
        a.diff(b, 'days') //[days, years, months, seconds, ...]
        alert(a);
```

Exists within packages config and moment.js included in scripts folder. Installed with package manager as on moment.js website.

Comment: did you include/require properly the moment js library?

Comment: include moment.js and this error will disappear.